# removing reporting service encryption key on tfs migration to new hardware

Tags: reporting-services, tfs, migration

I want to **move my tfs 2010 and sharepoint 2010 from one hardware to another**. the solution is clear. but the problem is that, because of a **crash** witch happened to my **reporting services** in source hardware, **I have lost the encryption key** witch is used for tfs reporting services. now I am installing new instances of sql server and reporting services on new hardware.

the question is this : **is there any way for recreating reporting services databases using a new encryption key on the destination hardware?** after moving tfs and sharepoint, I want to recreate reporting databases and use a new encryption key.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The only things that are encrypted are the SQL Database connection string for the OLAP and TFSWarehouse data sources. Then you backup/restore the database from one hardware configuration to another you should recreate them anyway. So the RS Key is of no use for you.

Make sure you follow the section "Configure Reporting and Analysis Services
" of the Microsoft procedure [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404869.aspx)

**UPDATE**
See [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsreporting/thread/fc53be12-2ebd-41c8-a66a-ccd4437033fd/), it gives you the procedure to restore the SQL Connections.

Comment: but The TFS Moving document says that I should backup RS key and Restore it in the new server

Comment: Yes, it's the procedure, but in your case you don't have them, so you'll have to patch the SQL connection by yourself. If you have the rs.key it's faster to migrate, but you still can do it manually. See my edit in the Answer.